# Table change witdh for last tr

Tags: css, html-table

[image]

I have this table and my problem is with last line because have a different width and some cells are combined.

The html is this

```
  <table border="1" width="820" cellpadding="2">
    <caption align="bottom">description</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>lorem ipsum</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5(3x4)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Nume produs</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>89,00</td>
        <td>89,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Nume produs</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>89,00</td>
        <td>89,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Cost livrare</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>15,00</td>
        <td>15,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Cost livrare</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>15,00</td>
        <td>15,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="210">
        <td colspan="1">Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td colspan="2">Lorem ipsum</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Lorem</td>

    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my try but I can't understand how to to do something like images. I use colspan and rowspan but I don't know how to use them correctly in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best i can do for you: http://jsfiddle.net/CvYm5/

```
<table border="1" width="820" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <th>lorem ipsum</th>
    <th>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</th>
    <th>lorem ipsum</th>
    <th>lorem ipsum</th>
    <th>lorem ipsum</th>
    <th>lorem ipsum</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5(3x4)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Nume produs</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>89,00</td>
    <td>89,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Nume produs</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>89,00</td>
    <td>89,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Cost livrare</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>15,00</td>
    <td>15,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Cost livrare</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>15,00</td>
    <td>15,00</td>
</tr>
<tr height="110">
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>Lorem</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td height="140">LOREM ISPUM 104 Lei</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time there's a vertical separation on some row, it must be 2 different cells on this row AND other rows as well (or be taken into account by a `colspan` value.

I copy-pasted your HTML code with some background color: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/awfvC
In last rows, you've a separation between the first 2 cells "LOREM IPSUM" and "LOREM IPSUM". So it's 2 cells (and the first one already has colspan="2" because of column 0, 1, 2, 3 in first rows... AND previous rows should have 2 cells (or higher value of colspan) where you've the name of products.

In red the cells you should take into account:

[image: edited table with missing rows and columns]

Comment: Thanks for answer , i put this in table but the result it`s not really good http://pastebin.com/GY5m10r2

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fiddle with required cells. Just put your height and width and you are done

http://jsfiddle.net/BC4A8/

```
Use RowSpan and Colspan to merge rows and cols
```